# Correct way to concatenate hashes for merkle tree

Tags: javascript, hash, keccak, merkle-patricia-tries

I'm using Richard Moore's ethers.js to create hashes of documents that will eventually be stored on the EVM. To create a merkle tree with many documents I'll need to hash together hashes. What's the correct/conical way to concatenate these before I apply the hashing function?

```
var left = 0xbe5b5152fcd01b6bf53f149bfd1493a49ec5e8ae94cc4c29a81563eea0e347f4;
var right = 0xe97032473c4f6788bf3f197518c925b296172520eae8df21f8ce2c6a1df54146;

// Is this the best way to concat?
var joined = left.toString(16) + right.toString(16);
var newHash = ethers.utils.keccak256( ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(joined) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an article](https://blog.ricmoo.com/merkle-air-drops-e6406945584d) that makes use of Merkle trees using ethers.js, in both JavaScript and Solidity.

Here is the [JavaScript](https://github.com/ricmoo/ethers-airdrop/blob/master/index.js#L154) for the Merkle tree creation and here is the [Solidity](https://github.com/ricmoo/ethers-airdrop/blob/master/AirDropToken.sol#L112) that verifies it.

Given the above example though, keep in mind you cannot use JavaScript numbers that way. You will need the left and right to be strings.

For example:

```
// JavaScript (with quotes)
var left = '0xbe5b5152fcd01b6bf53f149bfd1493a49ec5e8ae94cc4c29a81563eea0e347f4';
var right = '0xe97032473c4f6788bf3f197518c925b296172520eae8df21f8ce2c6a1df54146';
var newHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.concat([ left, right ]))

// Solidity (without quotes)
bytes32 left = 0xbe5b5152fcd01b6bf53f149bfd1493a49ec5e8ae94cc4c29a81563eea0e347f4;
bytes32 right = 0xe97032473c4f6788bf3f197518c925b296172520eae8df21f8ce2c6a1df54146;
bytes32 newHash = keccak256(left, right);
```

Comment: Perhaps it used to but as of v5 ethers' `keccak256` doesn't accept two values: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-keccak256